# Muan International Airport to Mokpo in late evening

Tags: airport-transfer, south-korea, late-arrival

I reach [Muan International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muan_International_Airport) Friday at 21:30 with no checked-in luggage.

I had booked the only guesthouse in the area via booking.com but this morning the owner sent me an email telling me that they are closed for repairs.

Now the nearest accommodation seems to be in [Mokpo](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Mokpo), 30 kilometers away.

**Question**: What is the cheapest way to go from Muan International Airport to Mokpo at 22:00?

What I tried:

- The airport does not seem to have an English website.
- The only public transportation shown by Google Maps is at 6AM in the morning.
- The only public transportation shown by rome2rio goes via [Gwangju](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Gwangju), which is not on the way at all, and actually very far away. Also, rome2rio does not show hours.

Answer (score 5):

With my poor Korean skills I found the following information, I am not very sure so any better answer is welcome.

1. Go to http://www.airport.co.kr
2. Click 전국공항 네트워크 (national airports), or the hamburger menu if on a small screen
3. Click 무안국제공항 (Muan International Airport)
4. In the 교통/주차 menu, click 대중교통 (public transport)
5. Scroll to the bottom of the page, there is a table of bus lines.
6. Find the row where the second column reads 무안국제공항 → 목포버스터미널 (Muan International Airport → Mokpo Bus Terminal) and click the arrow at the right
7. All scheduled times appear, find the last one. Currently it is:

> 11회(심야) : 무안국제공항(22:30) ☞ 무안버스터미널(22:45) ☞ 청계버스터미널(22:55) ☞ 목포버스터미널(23:10)

Translation:

> 11th bus (at night): Muan International Airport (22:30) ☞ Muan Bus Terminal (22:45) ☞ Cheonggye Bus Terminal (22:55) ☞ Mokpo Bus Terminal (23:10)

Direct link: http://www.airport.co.kr/muan/extra/bus/busList/layOut.do?langType=1&menuId=988

The price seems to be 5200 won.

The page also links to the official web page of the destination bus station: https://www.usquare.co.kr/kor/terminal/mokpo.do

## Update: I actually took that last bus

My plane was late, but I was among the first passengers to exit the plane. I got out of immigration at 22:29 (foreigners queue on the right, takes a long time for each passenger), rushed through customs, ran to the exit (good thing I had no checked-in luggage), turned right at the exit, they were two buses waiting:

- One for Gwangju (광주시) on the right
- One for Mokpo (목포시) on the left

The bus driver understood "Mokpo", I jumped in.
The bus leaved at 22:32, as 90% of the passengers were still lining up at immigration.

Comment: Actually, there are buses to Mokpo Intercity Bus Terminal from Muan airport Express Bus Terminal. I cannot share any link but we can easily find it from Kakao Map. It takes about one hour.

Comment: @Taladris: I guess you mean the 좌석 (the blue one) 1000? Kakao map says last bus departs Muan Airport at 22:02. Not sure how crowded Muan is for non-Korean passport control so can't say for sure, but probably could be doable. Only other option looks like taxi with Kakao estimate KRW 30000.